# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss5.x, struts-1

I am getting this error when getting sessionfactory from jboss JNDI and here is my source code.I have tried several times with many modifications but it has been not solved.
Thanks in advance.

### mysql-ds

which is placed in jboss default deploy folder.

```
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>jdbc/NeuraDS</jndi-name>
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/neurahmis</connection-url>
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
<user-name>admin</user-name>
<password>admin@123</password>
<min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
<max-pool-size>1000</max-pool-size>
<exception-sorter-class-   name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>  
</local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

### web.xml

Added in web.xml for datasource

```
<resource-ref>
<description>Database connection resource</description>   
<res-ref-name>Neura</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

### jboss-web.xml

Added in jboss-web.xml for jndi

```
<jboss-web>
<context-root>/neurads</context-root>
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>Neura</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<jndi-name>java:jdbc/NeuraDS</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml

These are my hibernate properties.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/jdbc/NeuraDs</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

### HibernateUtil.java

To obtain the session factory

```
sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to put entry in `web.xml` and `jobss-web.xml`. `mysql-ds.xml` should be sufficient to [binding a datasource to JNDI tree](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/Using_other_Databases.html#Using_other_Databases-Using_MySQL_as_the_Default_DataSource).

In the file `hibernate.cfg.xml`, you mentioned the datasource as `java:/jdbc/NeuraDs`, Can you correct it to `jdbc/NeuraDs` and then try. This is how I used it in my project and its working. The JNDI name should be identical to what you mentioned in `mysql-ds.xml`.

Please make sure that you check the start up logs to see any error related to this configuration.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply and sorry for seeing the post late. when i remove entry in web.xml and jobss-web.xml i am getting following error. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Can't call rollback when autocommit=true   But when i made the following modification in HibernateUtil class like System.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", "java:jdbc/NeuraDS");
      Configuration c=new Configuration();
      c.setProperties(System.getProperties());
      sessionFactory=c.configure().buildSessionFactory(); it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with reading the connection creation properties. When you directly give connection properties through system property it works. Something related to [basic hibernate](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/03/14/complete-hibernate-tutorial-with-example.html) set up looks wrong.